# youtube-api: how to get the json of list of last 20 videos uploaded on a channel

Tags: json, youtube-api

I am newbie. I got my api key for youtube-data-api.

I want to get the json which contains the last 20 videos on a channel. for example: https://www.youtube.com/user/ABCNews. I am not subscribed to it.

How to get it, what will be the url.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=20&type=video&order=date&part=snippet&forUsername=ABCnews&key=

I found it, and it gives me the list of videos.